# Mocking a annotation surrounding a method

Tags: java, junit, playframework-2.0, mockito

I have a own defined annotation (@BasicAuth) that I use for adding BasicAuth to a method.

Like this:

```
public class TokenController extends BaseController {
  @BasicAuth
  public static Result create() {
   ....
  }
}
```

It works like a charm but when I'm testing the create method I would like to switch off (or mock) the protection. Is that possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just create the `TokenController` using `new TokenController()` and call `create()`. The annotation will be ignored because you're creating it outside the framework.

Answer (score 0):

Yeap, it doesn't matter when you just used TokenController. Annotation is used in reflection